# Replicate clear:both element

Tags: html, css, css-float

Let's say you have three elements:

```
<header>
    <!-- stuff -->
</header>
<main style="background-color:red;">
    <!-- stuff -->
    <div style="float:left;height:300px;">tall stuff</div>
</main>
<footer style="background-color:blue;clear:both;">
    <!-- stuff -->
</footer>
```

Of course, the `div` will poke out of the bottom of the `main` element. This can be fixed inserting a `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` element as the last child of `main`. I hate doing that though (and my knowledge of this stuff is really out of date) and am wondering if there is an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with just CSS using pseudo elements:

```
main:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}
```

Comment: Agreed, don't need to use extra markup to clear floated elements. If yo are using sass you can create a mixin as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add `overflow:auto` to the parent element.

```
<header>
     stuff 
</header>
<main style="background-color:red;overflow:auto;">
     stuff 
    <div style="float:left;height:300px;">tall stuff</div>
</main>
<footer style="background-color:blue;clear:both;">
     stuff 
</footer>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dDLZ9/)**